# Flask RSTP Project converted into Django [HELP working FLASK]

Tags: python, django

I am hitting a roadblock trying to convert and embed a RTSP address to a django template.

I have a working dashboard but have not implemented anything regarding RTSP as I have not come across any helpful information.

I have seen solutions using HTML and Javascript and some django projects on github but most are unfinished or outdated and not working.

If anyone can direct me one how to do this using a view model container type setup that would be very much appreciated.

Here is the working flask version I have running but would like to get it working in django.

@pigrammer

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8081,host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

camera.py

```
import cv2
import imutils

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4')
        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        while(self.video.isOpened()):
            success, image = self.video.read()
            image = imutils.resize(image, width=350)
            print(image.shape)
            if success==True:
            # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
            # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
            # video stream.
                ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
                return jpeg.tostring()
```

Django I would like to incorprate it into

view.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import User
from .models import Articles
from .models import Comments
from .models import Timeclock
from .models import Rtspviewer
from django.db.models import F
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, Paginator
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime
# Create your views here.
def error_500(request):
    return render(request,'500.html')

def error_404(request,exception):
    return render(request,'404.html')

def error_403(request,exception):
    return render(request,'403.html')

def indexView(request):
    if 'user_token' not in request.session:
        return redirect("login")
    else:
        username = request.session['user_token']
        user_id = request.session['_auth_user_id']
        current_wrk = Timeclock.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).filter(current='1')
              
        if not current_wrk:
            currently = 0
        else:
            currently = 1
        return render(request,'dash/index.html',{'current':currently})
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @pigrammer sure I have found a working flask server version I am using currently but would like to have this built in to django.

Comment: @pigrammer I have updated the main post with some of my code